# How to list installed files in FreeBSD pkg?

Tags: freebsd, pkg

Is there a way to list the installed files with `pkg` for a certain package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pkg info -l PACKAGENAME` or `pkg info --list-files PACKAGENAME`. You can find the `-l` option in [man pkg-info](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-info&sektion=8&n=1).  (And you can in turn find the `pkg info` subcommand and a pointer to its aformentioned manual page in [man pkg](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=8&n=1).)

Comment: Beware the order of the arguments: `pkg -l info PACKAGENAME` will not produce desired output

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not documented in the man page for `pkg`, `pkg list PACKAGENAME` is the most concise way, and easiest to remember, at least for me.

One difference between this method and that proposed by @uzsolt is that `pkg info -l` produces output that is perhaps more suited for "human consumption," with minor touches of formatting:

```
$ pkg info -l mod_php73
mod_php73-7.3.7:
        /usr/local/libexec/apache24/libphp7.so
        /usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php73-7.3.7/LICENSE
        /usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php73-7.3.7/PHP301
        /usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php73-7.3.7/catalog.mk
```

`pkg list` OTOH produces more austere output, strictly a raw list of filenames, suitable for counting, iteration or other forms of "machine consumption":

```
$ pkg list mod_php73
/usr/local/libexec/apache24/libphp7.so
/usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php73-7.3.7/LICENSE
/usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php73-7.3.7/PHP301
/usr/local/share/licenses/mod_php73-7.3.7/catalog.mk
```

Comment: `list` is only an alias, check here: https://github.com/freebsd/pkg/blob/master/src/pkg.conf.sample#L71
If you use `info -ql` (note the `q`) you can receive same output as `list`.

Comment: @uzsolt Thanks for that information. That's partly why I qualified my answer with 'most concise' and 'easiest to remember.'

Comment: I didn't notice this alias - so your answer was useful. I wrote my comment because of "not documented in the man page", so I think it's understandable now, why "not documented" :)

Comment: @uzsolt IMO, it's worth documenting, though.  Given the paradigm of a "package," what more intuitive way is there to query the contents of a given package than to look at the "packing list," i.e. the `pkg list`? Hence for me, at least, easiest to remember.  Cheers!